# Correctly installing multiple OS versions on 2 drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader, nvme

I have a tough question.

I need to i install multiple linux versions and windows together on 2 drives without messing the bootloader.

Potentially important Hardware:
CPU ryzen 3600
MB Asrock B450
UEFI

So here's the thing. I currently have an NVME with Windows 10, which is also bitlocker encrypted so I have to enter its password every time I boot. I want this to be my default system.

Together with that, I want to put a SATA SSD which i will partition in 4 parts, 2 of which i will have with 2 different versions of Ubuntu, 1 oracle based OS and another edition of Windows 10, different from my current win 10 which is on the NVME.

How would you suggest that i take on the matter, so that i can install the 4 extra OS's on the sata SSD, and after  be able to chose the OS i want to boot trough the default windows Boot loader screen.

Also, would you suggest that i partition the SSD trough my current windows 10 partitioning tool?

Thank you in advance and please feel free to add any vital details i might need to know. Semi noob here.

Comment: This question is a bit broad and opinion-based and might get closed for that reason, but I'd suggest that you keep your EFI/boot partition where it is and make sure that the new installations also use that EFI.  This won't affect your BitLocker encryption, and when you choose Windows from GRUB, it just punts over to Windows' bootloader.  I'd also recommend against over-partitioning.  You can make "placeholder" partitions so they don't get assumed by other installations, just deleting the placeholder prior to the related installation. The installers will make appropriate partitions.

Comment: In UEFI turn off NVMe drive as difficult to physically disconnect. Install Windows as it wants multiple partitions, then use Windows to shrink your large NTFS partition. Make sure Windows works. Use gparted to create several 30GB partitions for / (root) and a larger ext4 data partition so you can have same data in both Linux. Perhap also a shared NTFS data partition. Make sure all installs are UEFI on gpt partitioned drives.http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  except Ubuntu now uses swap file, so no swap partition  required.

Comment: I would use VMs instead of multi-boot, since you seem to have not re-partitioned before, and since you want to keep BitLocker. Nobody *needs* to boot 4 OSs on bare metal. That means you are likely either experimenting or testing. VMs are perfect for experimenting; they are disposable. VMs are great for testing, since they can be easily reset after a test. Also each OS will consume a lot less space on your new SSD.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Thank you guys!

@Nmah, I should likely follow oldfred's procedure as it is most detailed. Especially since I am new to Linux and it will take some time for me to adapt. 

user535733 I have been juggling around with VM's but sadly their inability to properly utilize connected devices and also the super complex re-routing settings for the graphics card, make VM's pretty limited. That's why I want to install them on the metal and experiment without limits.

waltinator I'm aware of the terms but the answer to my question is much more tricky than the historically oriented wiki answers.